# Java Selenium. 2 column array. 2 elements to fill out on page. 1 loop per row

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am searching but am struggling to find the right wording to get results.

I have a .csv file with 2 columns. I need to navigate to a page, sendKeys column 1 to element 1, sendKeys column 2 to element 2, click element 3, click element 4, loop for next row until no more rows exist in the array.

I have everything figured out except "sendKeys column 1 to element 1, sendKeys column 2 to element 2".

I have this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("FilePathway"));
ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] record = new String[2];
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    record = scan.nextLine().split(",");
    records.add(record);
}
// now records has your records.
// here is a way to loop through the records (process)
for (String[] temp : records) {
    for (String temp1 : temp) {
        System.out.print(temp1 + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Works like a charm to print the array to the console. Pretty sure:

```
for (String[] temp : records) {
    for (String temp1 : temp) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("Element1")).sendKeys(temp1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Element2")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Element3")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Element4")).click();
    }
```

would work if I just had one column and one element to fill out, but how do I get column 2 and element 2 in there?

Comment: Why do you have the inner for loop, instead of just using `temp[0]` to refer to column 1 and `temp[1]` to refer to column 2?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("FilePathway"));
ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] line = new String[2];
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    line = scan.nextLine().split(",");
    records.add(line);
}
// now records has your records.
// here is a way to loop through the records (process)
for (String[] record : records) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("Element1")).sendKeys(record[0]);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Element2")).sendKeys(record[1]);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Element3")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Element4")).click();
}
```

I changed some variable names to make things read better... `record` to `line`, `temp` to `record`, and then removed the inner loop and replaced it with `record[0]` and `record[1]`. `line` is just a line from the CSV file, `record` is a singular record from `records`, and `record[]` is a way to access individual records using array notation.